# Azure Service Fabric VMExtensionProvisioningError

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to create secure service fabric cluster from Azure Portal with primary certificate uploaded to key-vault.

All required resources are being created. Exception occurs on Virtual machine scale set, operation `Write VirtualMachineScaleSets` reports:

```
 "properties": {
        "statusCode": "Conflict",
        "statusMessage": "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\"message\":\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"VMExtensionProvisioningError\",\"message\":\"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'VMDiagnosticsVmExt_vmNodeType0Name'. Error message: \\\"Monitoring Agent not reporting success after launch\\\".\"}]}}"
    }
```

Because internal operation `Write Deployments` is being failed, and no detailed message.

Comment: I had same issue. Redeploying Service Fabric helped me.

Comment: Can you supply any additional error logs from Event Viewer on one of the VMSS instances?

Comment: I also see the problem. One of three VMSS fail. Identical ARM template and setup, just different name sequence. Rerunning sometimes resolves the problem. Other times it seems that deleting and rerunning is the only solution.